# Summarize repeated data in a Postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres 9.1 table called ngram_sightings. Each row is a record of seeing an ngram in a document. An ngram can appear multiple times in a given document.

```
 CREATE TABLE ngram_sightings
(
    ngram VARCHAR,
    doc_id INTEGER
);
```

I want summarize this table in another table called ngram_counts.

```
CREATE TABLE ngram_counts
(
    ngram VARCHAR PRIMARY INDEX,

    -- the number of unique doc_ids for a given ngram
    doc_count INTEGER,

    -- the count of a given ngram in ngram_sightings
    corpus_count INTEGER
);
```

What is the best way to do this?

ngram_sightings is ~1 billion rows.
Should I create an index on ngram_sightings.ngram first?

Comment: What is a ngram in your program? Just a sequence of `n` tokens(words)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot!

```
INSERT INTO ngram_counts (ngram, doc_count, corpus_count)
SELECT
  ngram
, count(distinct doc_id) AS doc_count
, count(*) AS corpus_count 
FROM ngram_counts
GROUP BY ngram;
```

-- EDIT --

Here is a longer version using some temporary tables.  First, count how many documents each ngram is associated with. I'm using 'tf' for "term frequency" and 'df' for "doc frequency", since you are heading in the direction of [tf-idf vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) and you may as well use the standard language, it will help with the next few steps.

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ngram_df AS
 SELECT
   ngram
 , count(distinct doc_id) AS df
 FROM ngram_counts
 GROUP BY ngram;
```

Now you can create table for the total count of each ngram.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ngram_tf AS
 SELECT
   ngram
 , count(*) AS tf
 FROM ngram_counts
 GROUP BY ngram;
```

Then join the two on ngram.

```
CREATE TABLE ngram_tfidf AS
SELECT
  tf.ngram
, tf.tf
, df.df
FROM ngram_tf
INNER JOIN ngram_df ON ngram_tf.ngram = ngram_df.ngram;
```

At this point, I expect you will be looking up ngram quite a bit, so it makes sense to index the last table on ngram.  Keep me posted!

Comment: How can I make this query run the fastest? I'm imagining it's going to take hours. Should I index ngram_sightings.ngram?

Comment: If you like, yes, but I guess the biggest cost is probably the distinct doc_id.  I don't have your data, but if you run the explain plan it will tell you where the bottle neck is.  Another method would be to create a separate temporary table of just ngram, doc_id, count(*) pairs and join them for the final.  This is easy to understand and should be a bit quicker.  Does that help?

Comment: Is this what you mean?

    `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temporary_counts;
    CREATE TABLE temporary_counts AS
        SELECT
            ngram,
            doc_id,
            COUNT(*)
        FROM ngram_sightings
        GROUP BY doc_id, ngram;

    CREATE TABLE ngram_counts AS
        SELECT
            ngram,
            COUNT(DISTINCT doc_id) AS doc_count,
            SUM(count) corpus_count
        FROM temporary_counts
        GROUP BY ngram;`